# Is $\log^22^k = (\log2^k)^2$?

Tags: notation, logarithms

Does the square of $\log^22^k$ include whole $2^k$?
Is $\log^22^k = (\log2^k)^2 = \log2^k \cdot \log2^k = k^2$?

The base of my $\log$ is $2$.

Comment: You mean the square of $\log2^k$?

Comment: That's the question - what does the notation $\log^2 2^k$ mean? @John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $ \log^22^k$ is a very confusing notation.

I'd rather go with $$ (\log2^k)^2 = (\log2^k)\times(\log2^k) = k^2(\log2)^2 $$

But again its down to preference.

If we're considering base 2, yes, the answer simplifies to $k^2$

Answer (score 2):

$\log^2 x$ notation is a very annoying one. People use it for both $\log \log x$ and $(\log x)^2$. Here's my theory on how this notational nightmare came about.

In general, with a function $f$, we tend to expect $f^2 (x)$ to be $f(f(x))$ (composition) while $(f(x))^2$ means exactly that - the value of $f(x)$ squared.

However, notation of $\sin x, \cos x, \tan x$ developed where $\sin^2 x, \cos^2 x, \tan^2 x,$ meant $(\sin x)^2, (\cos x)^2, (\tan x)^2$. In this case, the error is not so egregious since it is extremely uncommon to see $\sin \sin x$, since it doesn't really make sense as a concept. That is, $\sin x$ takes in an angle and gives you a ratio, so it doesn't usually make sense to then take the $\sin$ of a ratio when its argument should be an angle.

Then, people used $f^2(x)$ for functions like $\log$ to mean $(f(x))^2$ since they were used to doing it for trigonometric functions and failed to see the nuance above of why it works out in that case.

EDIT: Okay, now I'm confused. Is OP asking if $\log^2 2^k = \log^2 (2^k)$ or if $\log^2 2^k = (\log^2 2)^k$ or is he asking about the exponent of $2$ over the $\log$? His first statement implies the first but his second statement seems to imply the latter...

Comment: I wanted to know if $log^22^k = log2^k * log2^k = k*k$

Comment: @bogALT As opposed to WHAT? Your question says you are confused about notation-- WHICH notation

Comment: or if you prefer: is $log^22^k = (log2^k)^2$?

Comment: @bogALT Okay so then why is your question asking if $\log^2 2^k$ includes the whole $2^k$ or not... that's a different question (is $\log^2 2^k = (\log^2 2)^k$?)

Comment: It may be because my english is not so good and probably it doesn't make sence in english. Sorry

Comment: The more used sense is just square, not composition. For functions too. The reason to change a bit the notation nowdays is because it fit best under LATEX when you write $f(x)^2$ instead of $f^2(x)$. The confusion come, IMO, that for some operators powering is the same that composition... and some people tend to use functions as some kind of operator where this rule isnt true.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_2 2^k = k$$

Squaring both sides:

$$\log_2^2 2^k = k^2$$

The expression $(\log_2^2 2)^k$ is not a useful expression as it simply evaluates to one, so the above interpretation is almost certainly what one would mean when writing $\log_2^2 2^k$

Comment: I think the question is not about the value of $(\log 2^k)^2$, but whether $\log^2 2^k = (\log^2 2)^k$ or $\log^2 (2^k)$ - one of notational interpretation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks, I amended my answer

Comment: But the "not a useful expression" answer is not helpful if the question then becomes about $\log^2 a^b$. Sometimes, we get "useless expressions" in special cases of good general rules. There are better reasons why $\log^2 a^b = \log^2(a^b)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if you can write a better answer than mine than please do so and I'll gladly retract my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight flaw in your working out.
$$ \log2^k \cdot \log2^k = k^2 (\log2)^2$$
Since we have no reason to suppose that $(\log2)^2=1$, I'd have to say that your last step is causing the error.

Comment: Did you skip the line "The base of my log is 2"?

Comment: He mentions he's using log base 2, so we have every reason to say that $(\log2)^2 = 1$

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out @ThomasAndrews and Alec. Yes I completely missed that line, my apologies to the OP! So yes then, the rest of his work is sound.